# How to create custom shapes menu in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

By the "Shapes Menu," I mean the menu that you get to from the ribbon by going to Home -> Shapes.

I would like to either:

1. Choose my own shapes for within the Shapes menu, including changing the names of separators
2. Create my own ribbon menu from scratch that allows you to create a gallery with separators

Here is a picture:

[image]

Note: I'm interested in doing this for Powerpoint 2013, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: PowerPoint doesn't allow you to add new shape types as such.  You can add a new gallery control to the ribbon using RibbonX code, and a click on one of the gallery items could cause code in an add-in to execute; that code might pull a pre-created shape from an external PPTX file, for example.  IOW, it can be done, but it's not necessarily a simple project.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - My question is about wanting to create a menu like in the picture -- gallery, plus divider lines. Is it possible to use RibbonX code to do that? I already have code for pre-created shapes and that part will not be difficult.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to do that with RibbonX code.  I haven't created any galleries myself, but my RibbonX "go-to" book, "RibbonX, Customizing the Office 2007 Ribbon" by Martin/Puls/Hennig explains how to do it.  Highly recommend the book to anyone who wants to work with the ribbon.  That and the Office Ribbon Editor from http://www.leafcreations.org

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - Thanks for the book recommendation. It seems insanely useful. Unfortunately, the chapter on galleries didn't address my question. It shows how to make a general gallery, which includes one set of icons... but, it doesn't allow you to create separators that show many galleries. Any other ideas?

Comment: Again, haven't done it myself, but look at the following chapter in the book, Chapter 9.  It looks like a menu control can include multiple items, and one or more of these items can be a gallery.

Comment: I am not aware of any tools that allow you to do achieve this using just VBA. I'd investigate [**VSTO**](http://invertedindex.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/vsto-how-to-create-a-toolbar-for-an-excel-add-in/) if I were you :)

Comment: option 1 is not possible afaik. Option 2 is doable and I have done something similar myself both in a VBA addin (simplest) and C#.NET (better language for more complex larger addins) COM addin (@mehow VSTO is absolutely not necessary if you haven't a licence already, although it does make certain aspects simpler). Galleries can have other controls (inc. seperators) inside them. Play around with a ribbon xml editor to see what is allowed, or else read (by read, I mean hook up to your preferred xml editor) the schema (e.g. http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=1574)

Answer (score 1):

A global intro to the Ribbon is available on the Microsoft site at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx. Be sure to check out parts 2 and 3, links to which are located in left menu of that page above.

More specifically, you might find some useful guidance on building a Gallery at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd904887%28v=office.12%29.aspx.

In terms of modifying the XML behind ribbons, I use the Custom UI editor. You can download it at http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/08/07/7293.aspx